# Why does Java Stack have a search method?

Tags: java, stack

From what I know about stacks, it seems like this method goes against the whole point of a stack- if you need to know where in your stack a specific element is then why are you using a stack at all?

Edit: I'm not trying to waste anyone's time or ask dumb questions, I'm a student who's honestly just trying to figure out the rationale behind this function so that I can become a better programmer

Comment: Just because a container has an ordering, you think that you shouldn't be able to inspect its elements?

Comment: You will have to ask people who implemented it in Java. Besides `Stack` is obesolete and you should use `Deque` implementations instead.

Comment: Some of the older Java collection implementations, and indeed large portions of the JDK besides, have really bad implementations or APIs. The only reason that a lot of that crap hasn't been removed is backwards compatibility. So trust your instincts - if it seems bad, it probably is. It's not automatically good just because it's in the JDK.

Comment: @azurefrog My point is that when you're using a stack you're not supposed to have to care about where exactly in the stack your elements are

Answer (score 2):

I would put it like that:

Java has its inconsistencies and this is one of them. 
If you take a deeper look you will find that Stack is a subclass of Vector and inherits its mehtods which also seem to make not that much of a sense.

Programming languages are living and growing things made by people and I think you can always find things that don't make sense or things that you wish would have been made in a better way (whatever 'better' means).
In some you will find more in some you will find less flaws.